# Binding to WPF parent Grid panel's property fails, yet yields no binding warning messages

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to something I thought was fairly simple.  I want to make the border within my grid appear whenever keyboard focus is inside the grid.

But the binding is not working and I cannot spot what's wrong with it. I'm hoping someone can spot where I went wrong.

I created a simple test app to illustrate the problem.  Here's the content of the window

```
<StackPanel>
    <!-- This text box is just so that something else can have focus at times -->
    <TextBox Width="200" Height="20"/>

    <!--
    This grid should show its border whenever keyboard focus is within 
    I even have an event handler dumping out the new value of when it changes.
    -->
    <Grid x:Name="DetailGrid"
          Width="400" Height="400" Focusable="True"
          IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged="DetailGrid_OnIsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged">

        <Border  BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0" >
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, ElementName=DetailGrid}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>

            <!-- This text box is just so that the grid can get keyboard focus within -->
            <TextBox Width="200" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

And the code-behind event handler which confirms that the property has changed to what I expect

```
    private void DetailGrid_OnIsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DetailGrid keyboard focus within = " + (bool) e.NewValue)  ;
    }
```

- The "DetailGrid" contains a zero-thickness border around a text box.
- The trigger on the border binds to the IsKeyboardFocusWithin of the
  parent DetailGrid.
- If the user clicks the text box, the IsKeyboardFocusWithin property of the grid gets set to true (I have verified this in code-behind).
- The trigger says that when that IsKeyboardFocusWithin property of DetailGrid gets set to true, that border thickness should get increased to 3.

But that's not happening.

I tried changing the Debug output window settings to be much more verbose about the WPF binding but I don't see any problems there.

I tried changing the binding to use FindAncestor but that made no difference.

My gut tells me this has to be something incredibly simple and dumb but I can't see it.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your `Border` in XAML to this instead:

```xml
<Border BorderBrush="Black" >
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, ElementName=DetailGrid}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>

    <!-- This text box is just so that the grid can get keyboard focus within -->
    <TextBox Width="200" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Border>
```

I removed the `BorderThickness="0"` markup from the `Border` definition because it has a [higher precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence#dependency-property-setting-precedence-list) than a value set through a `Style` `Setter` so your `Setter` couldn't override it. I moved this default value to a default `Style` `Setter` as you can see.

I also changed the `BorderBrush` to `Black` so that you can see it become visible.

Comment: Grrrr.  I  *knew* it was something that was going to make me feel really dumb.  Right in front of my face.  Thanks so much for you help.